How subscribe a Web push Protocol with JS on a PWA on iOS
I received a commission for a PWA that uses the Web push Protocol for receives notifications from the server.
The PWA is in WASM, with Blazor .NET 8. I used JS for the entire Web push architecture. The PWA works well on Android, Windows, Apple and iOS.
But I have a big problem implementing Web Push Protocol notifications on iOS > 16.4 version.
From what I understand you must have an Apple development license - which I have -. But I don't understand if I have to create keys and certificates for an iOS app that I will not use (I have my blazor PWA) and how to connect in JS to which server, for receive the token of the subscription.
I only find references to make native Apps in iOS, but nothing that can help me if the app comes from a world outside iOS.
Someone can help me to manage Web Push Protocol with JS script in iOS ?
Thanks a lot.

No, you don't need an Apple Developer license... you are reading outdated documentation. Apple now supports the standard (Push API). Note that there are some additional requirements for Apple devices: for example the user must first add the PWA to Home Screen before being able to subscribe to your notifications.

sometimes it's hard to distinguish between legacy and current documentation. It would be nice to always add a date to it! ;)
